# Passing parameter to ng-click directive, within custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using `ng-repeat` in the template for a custom directive as follows:

```
<li ng-repeat="image in images">
    <img ng-src="{{image.url}}" ng-click="togglePhoto({{$index}})">
</li>
```

When rendered on the page the source looks like

```
<li ng-repeat="image in images" class="ng-scope">
    <img ng-src="http://example.com/example.jpg" ng-click="togglePhoto(1)" src="http://example.com/example.jpg">
</li>
```

I have the function `togglePhoto` defined in my directive. Without the `{{index}}` parameter being passed in it works and the function is called. With the index, it doesn't fire.

How do I get the index of the photo clicked into the `togglePhoto` function?

Comment: How is `togglePhoto(x)` defined?

Answer (score 36):

Figured this out. Hope it helps anyone else stuck on it.

Firstly this

```
ng-click="togglePhoto({{$index}})"
```

Should be

```
ng-click="togglePhoto($index)"
```

Braces not needed!

Secondly I found that you can pass the event object into the click function eg

```
ng-click="togglePhoto($event)"
```

Then catch that event and find out what element trigged it in your click function

```
$scope.togglePhoto = function(e)
{
    console.log(e.currentTarget)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the issue is that you are using the double curly braces inside of the ng-click, and angular doesn't like that.

Try changing your repeater to this (note there are no curly braces around $index):

```
<li ng-repeat="image in images">
    <img ng-src="{{image.url}}" ng-click="togglePhoto($index)">
</li>
```

I also put together a working jsfiddle to show that this works.

http://jsfiddle.net/n02ms8s0/4/