# Fire directive, refresh, & pass parameter on ng-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-click

#### tldr;

I need to fire a custom directive/jQuery plugin on `ng-click` and pass a parameter to it then reload that page so the parameter's value takes place. So on reload instead of there being 3 results in my Google Map, there should be 50 results showing.

---

#### Disclaimer

I've done a ton of reading on firing directive on ng-click as well as passing parameters to directive (particularly [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18479096/angular-js-passing-parameter-to-ng-click-directive-within-custom-directive) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725938/angularjs-how-to-pass-arguments-functions-to-a-directive) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432198/passing-variable-to-angular-directive)) but I am fairly new to AngularJS so I'm still a bit naive to all the greatness of Angular and how to utilize it properly...

#### Background

I created a jQuery plugin for a Google Maps API app I'm creating. The app is using AngularJS also. The plugin creates a map and shows 3 locations to the user [plugin code here](https://github.com/jamez14/TrailFinder/blob/master/js/map.js). Under the map I have the list of 3 locations in a table. I also have a button that says *more results* which should return 50 more locations.

#### Question

What is the best way to...

1. Pass a new parameter to my plugin/directive? Currently on page load I load the directive and fire the plugin by `<div tfinder-map="{queryLimit: 3}">`. Ideally I'd like to be passing 50 when I click the *more results* button.
2. Along with passing the param to my directive/plugin on click of *more results*, I would like it to essentially fire the directive and reload the page so the 50 results show up, instead of just 3.

After reading other questions, I think passing a param to my directive would go something like this (although I'm sure the syntax is wrong):

`ng-click="tfinder-map(queryLimit: 50)"`

And to be able to persist that value as the page reloads, the only way I could think to do that would be via a query string argument in the URL.

I also did a little reading about **$route.reload()** which sounds interesting, I just don't know the best way to implement this to do a reload with params.

#### The code

My current directive looks like this:

```
directive('tfinderMap', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
        $(elm).tfindermap(scope.$eval(attrs.tfinderMap));
    }
};
```

})

And in jQuery it'd be

```
$('#foo').tfindermap({queryLimit: 3})
```

The actual jQuery plugin can be viewed **[here on Github](https://github.com/jamez14/TrailFinder/blob/master/js/map.js)**

Also, here's the UI if it helps visualize it

[image: the UI]

*clicking the more results button should make 50 results appear as opposed to 3*

Comment: Can't you somehow add a function to the plugin that "reloads" the necessary stuff (e.g. locations) and then just trigger that function, instead of having to persist a value and reload the page ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem that's a good way of looking at it. I'll look into that. Thanks!