# How to pass parameter(id) in URL using ng-click to view subdocument of specific user in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to pass the parameter `id` in a URL using `ng-click` in Angularjs, I am doing this because of I want to view a specific user subdocument data in a separate page.

```
<tr ng-repeat="register in registerlist | filter:searchText">
  <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
  <td>{{register.name}}</td>
  <td>{{register.email}}</td>
  <td>{{register.mobile_no}}</td>
  <td>{{register.area_name}}</td>
  <td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
            ng-click="RegisterView(register._id); showOrder = !showOrder">View</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

URL example: `localhost:8080//register/5426ced88b49d2e402402205`

Here this above user had subdocument, so i need to view the subdocument in a separate page.

Controller:

```
$scope.RegisterView = function(id) {
  $scope.IsVisible = $scope.IsVisible ? false : true;
  $http.get('/auth/register-list/' + id).success(function(response){
    $scope.bookinglist = response.booking;
  });
};
```

Comment: can you post your `RegisterView(register._id)` function in controller

Comment: see above i have updated my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing parameter to ng-click directive, within custom directive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18479096/passing-parameter-to-ng-click-directive-within-custom-directive)

Comment: Possibly related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039926/adding-parameter-to-ng-click-function-inside-ng-repeat-doesnt-seem-to-work

Comment: but id is not visible in url

Comment: Could you post your RegisterView controller function.

Comment: Are you maintaining states? If so, you can use `$state.go()` with parameters  and handle routes.

Comment: yeah i posted see above

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$location` in your `$scope.RegisterView` function to navigate to other page.
something like this `$location.path('/register/5426ced88b49d2e402402205')`

Comment: This makes sense, because `$http.get` as mentioned in the question is making a GET request and which doesn't redirect to a URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see your subdocument in seperate page then simply use :

```
<a target="_blank" >
  // apply target to that div where you are using subdocument
</a>
```

And if You have id in your `register` then you can directly call it as `RegisterView(register.id)`

```
$scope.RegisterView = function(id){
    $scope.IsVisible = $scope.IsVisible ? false : true;
    $http.get('/auth/register-list/' + id).success(function(response){
        $scope.bookinglist = response.booking;
    });
};
```

TEMPLATE

```
<button type="button" ng-click="RegisterView(register.id)"></button>
```

Comment: where i should use target="_blank"

Comment: you said you want to open subdocument in new page so if you use `targer="_blank" it open new page on-click button or anchor

Comment: am asking where i should use **target="_blank"** in button or where

Comment: ok use it in button tag so when you click on button you can see new page

Comment: i need to send my id through url...this is what my question

Comment: target="_blank" will not work in button. If you want to use, use it in <a> tag and apply some css to <a> to look like button

Comment: yes target is not accessible in <button> tag but you can use it like: `<a target="_blank" > <button> </button> </a>`